# openshift environment variable not used in virtualenv

Tags: python, environment-variables, openshift, iaas

I can't understand why my custom env variables aren't read during app execution, but if I type env command or use python shell they looks ok.

For example:
if I ssh to my app and type:

```
$ env | grep AMAZON
AMAZON_KEY=...
AMAZON_SECRET=...
```

and this is correct, it's my custom variable. But if I exec the application I've go:

```
$ KeyError: 'AMAZON_KEY'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try stopping and starting your application with the rhc command (not a restart) and see if that helps.

Comment: that could just trigger a restart, do an rhc stop and rhc start and see if it helps.

Comment: Do any of the default ones work? The other environment variables you see when you run env ?

Comment: all the standard variables works fine... now if (via ssh) I call export I can see the variables (declare -x AMAZON_KEY="...)

Comment: Can you post some of the code you are using to access the env variables?